# End a Python function after a certain time?

Tags: python, timer, timeout

For example, I have this function:

```
some_global_varible = ""
def bob(some_argument, some_more):
    import time
    for x in range(10):
        print("Working")
        time.sleep(1)
    return "I finished and this is my result"
```

How can I run this function for certain amount of time, and if it's not finish in the time end it. But also if it finish get the output of the return (if the is one, because maybe there is none and it simply end).

Also this won't be run in Unix, because I had see some example for Unix that don't work in Windows. Also if you could change the global variable form inside the function it would be perfect, but that as a extra.

First the rest and if it possible (If it not possible to detect an end without the return it doesn't matter, I can include a return just fro that. Like: return "This is just for ending")

**EDIT:**
The "bob" funtion is an example for a function that takes 10 seconds, but the plan is to use it on other functions, that can take an undefined amount of time. And that function can't be edited to add simply something to stop it at some time seconds.

A better example could be "pep" as it wouldn't end by itself.

```
def pep():
    import time
    while True:
        print("Working")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use time.time() to get the current time in seconds before you start your loop and then at the end of each for loop, check how long has passed since then and if it's too long then you can return.

```
def bob(some_argument, some_more):
    import time
    start = time.time()
    for x in range(10):
        print("Working")
        time.sleep(1)
        if time.time() - start > 5:
            return "I took too long"
    return "I finished and this is my result"
```

Obviously replace 5 with the time you want to use, but this code gives me this output:

```
Working
Working
Working
Working
Working
'I took too long'
```

Comment: I can't edit the function. The "bob" function was only an example, i'm not going to use that one.

Answer (score -2):

You may use the break;

For example if the value of the loop counter meets a following condition like this:

```
if condition:
   break;
```

this will surely end the loop.

Comment: I can't edit the function. The "bob" function was only an example, i'm not going to use that one.